# XML syntax highlighting does not work

Tags: listings, highlighting, xml

How do I make comments highlighted in the form:

```
<!-- ======= Processing Root tag =======   -->
```

. This is not working.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{listings, color}

\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.4,0.4,0.4}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.6}
\definecolor{cyan}{rgb}{0.0,0.6,0.6}

\lstloadlanguages{XML}

\lstdefinelanguage{XML}
{
  morestring=[b]",
  morestring=[s]{>}{<},
  morecomment=[s]{<?}{?>},
  morecomment=[s][\color{orange}]{<!--}{-->},
  stringstyle=\color{black},
  identifierstyle=\color{darkblue},
  keywordstyle=\color{cyan},
  morekeywords={xmlns,version,type}
}

\lstdefinestyle{listXML}{language=XML, extendedchars=true,  belowcaptionskip=5pt, xleftmargin=1.8em, xrightmargin=0.5em, numbers=left, numberstyle=\small\ttfamily\bf, frame=single, breaklines=true, breakatwhitespace=true, breakindent=0pt, emph={}, emphstyle=\color{red}, basicstyle=\small\ttfamily, columns=fullflexible, showstringspaces=false, commentstyle=\color{gray}\upshape}

\begin{document}
 XSLT listing:
 \begin{lstlisting}[style=listXML]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"     version="1.0">
<!-- ======= Processing Root tag =======   -->
<xsl:template match="Root">
    <TeXML>
      <TeXML escape="0">
                \documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
                \usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
                \usepackage{pscyr}
                \usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
                \usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
                \usepackage{longtable}
                \usepackage[a4paper, left=30mm, right=15mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}
                \usepackage{indentfirst}
                \usepackage{fixltx2e}
         </TeXML>
      <env name="document">
        <cmd name="clearpage"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="BasicInfo | StatusInfo"/>
      </env>
    </TeXML>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- ======= Types of opening ====== -->
  <xsl:template match="ConsDescr">
    <cmd name="par"/>
    <cmd name="textbf">
....
\end{lstlisting}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 15):

The problem is that the following two lines in your `\lstdefinelanguage{XML}` are in conflict:

```
morestring=[s]{>}{<},
morecomment=[s][\color{orange}]{<!--}{-->},
```

In addition, doesn't `\lstdefinelanguage{XML}` redefine the XML language settings, thereby losing a lot of configs? One of the most noticeable drawbacks is that you can no longer access `tagstyle`, while the `identifierstyle` setting would highlight both tag names and contents (the embedded LaTeX code).

Would it be feasible for you to move all the settings into `\lstdefinestyle` instead, dropping `morestring=[s]{>}{<}`, and using `tagstyle` in place of `identifierstyle`?

```
\lstdefinestyle{listXML}{language=XML, extendedchars=true,  belowcaptionskip=5pt, xleftmargin=1.8em, xrightmargin=0.5em, numbers=left, numberstyle=\small\ttfamily\bf, frame=single, breaklines=true, breakatwhitespace=true, breakindent=0pt, emph={}, emphstyle=\color{red}, basicstyle=\small\ttfamily, columns=fullflexible, showstringspaces=false, commentstyle=\color{gray}\upshape,
morestring=[b]",
morecomment=[s]{<?}{?>},
morecomment=[s][\color{orange}]{<!--}{-->},
keywordstyle=\color{cyan},
stringstyle=\color{black},
tagstyle=\color{darkblue},
morekeywords={xmlns,version,type}
}
```

This is the output I got:

[image]

Comment: @Youra_P You're welcome. :-) If this answer has solved your problem, it would be much appreciated if you could "accept" it by clicking the tick mark next to it (you may have to mouse-over the upvote count area to see it). Only when there is an accepted answer (even if it's the only answer given), will a question be deemed "answered" on stackexchange.

Comment: This is the first Latex XML Highlighting code that doesn't break with my XML files. Thanks